# How to convert following react router dom version 5 code to version 6.30

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to convert following code into `react-router-dom` version 6.0. it is giving following `error:createBrowserRouter' (imported as 'createBrowserRouter') was not found in 'react-router-dom' (possible exports:`

```
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import routesConfig from "./routesConfig";

const router = createBrowserRouter(routesConfig);

const App = () => {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
};

export default App;
```

Comment: What `react-router-dom` v5 or v6.0 code exactly are you trying to convert? `createBrowserRouter` was *just* introduced in `react-router-dom@6.4.0`, so I suppose the first thing to do if you want to use it is to update to ***at least*** `react-router-dom@6.4.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `createBrowserRouter` and `RouterProvider` were introduced in `react-router-dom@6.4.0`. If you want to use them then you should ensure you've installed ***at least*** the 6.4.0 version.

Install/upgrade by running the following:

```
npm i -s react-router-dom@6.4
```

This will install *and* update the package.json file with the latest 6.4.x version which is v6.4.1 at the moment of this posting.

OFC, if you just want to upgrade to whatever the latest version is then run:

```
npm i -s react-router-dom@latest
```